# Classical model for neutrino oscillations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass, neutrinos, oscillators

Does there exist any classical analogue or model for neutrino oscillations in two as well as three flavor scenarios? I just went through the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_oscillation#Classical_analogue_of_neutrino_oscillation which unfortunately does not give a clear picture of what is actually happening. Could someone help?

Comment: What is it èxactly that you don't understand about the example in Wikipedia?

Comment: See http://cerncourier.com/cws/article/cern/28028 which can be generalized to three penduli.

Comment: @Noiralef the Wikipedia, neither gives the form of the displacement of each pendulum ($x_a$  and $x_b$)as a function of time nor does it give the displacement of the normal modes ($x_1$ and $x_2$) as a function of time.  While as in neutrinos, I know the time dependence of the flavor and mass eigenstates.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Just solve the penduli problem, and if needed invert the normal mode back to the original coordinates. In this analogy the original coordinates are the flavour eigenstates and the normal modes the mass eigenstates..

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, thanks. Yeah, I'm going through the coupled penduli problem. Confronted by some complicated differential equations.

Comment: @Seeker of course you need to linearize, i.e. small angle approximation.